# remove lists containing less than 3 character strings

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists

`list_of_lists = [['stringxyz', ','], ['WER', 'stringz'], ['F.7.T.', 'UZ'], ['WWW', 'stringy'], [None, ''], [None, 'Frahm']]`

that contains lists, that contain strings of **character length <3** (see first and third lists above)

I want to **remove those lists** from the lists of lists

**desired ouput:**

`list_of_lists = [['WER', 'stringz'], ['WWW', 'stringy']]`

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to test whether a string is under 3 characters long? Do you know how to figure out whether a list contains any such string? Do you know how to filter a list based on a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
# use any to check if any sub-list has None in it or has an element shorter than 3 characters 
[s_l for s_l in list_of_lists if not (None in s_l or any(len(x)<3 for x in s_l))]
[['WER', 'stringz'], ['WWW', 'stringy']]
```